# Tooling to keep Pull Requests at a reasonable size

Tags: git, github, pull-request

For simplicity assume that we're using `git` with `GitHub`.

In a typical dev cycle we create a branch and then commit changes against that branch until the overall change is complete and then submit a Pull Request (PR) from that branch to `master`.

This is a typical cycle that most of you are probably familiar with and have worked with at some point.

I am looking for some tooling that will run on each commit to the branch and generate warnings when the number of lines of code changed hits configured levels. (i.e. between two branches - in this case the second branch is master)

The problem that I'm trying to solve is to prevent PRs from having too many changes in them.

Comment: You first say "on each commit", but then "between two branches", by which I assume you mean commits as identified by branch names. You need to decide here: is it OK if commit #1 changes 5 lines, then #2 changes 5, and so on, until after 1000 commits, there are 5000 lines of changes? Or is that forbidden because the maximum number of lines of changes is 500, so that this maxes out at 100 commits?

Comment: @torek - the number of lines changed between 2 branches. Each commit to a branch may increase or decrease that number relative to the other branch. The objective is to identify tooling that will alert the developer to the size of the PR they'll be generating when the number of lines changed becomes large.

Comment: OK: you don't care if commit #1 adds a million lines and commit #2 deletes the same million lines, since the sum of the commits is to make no change. You'll need a GitHub web hook to alert you to the pull request, and in your web hook, compare the final commit in the pull request (`refs/pull/<number>/head`) to the commit at the other branch (which I think you will have to find via GitHub API). You can use `git diff-tree` to get the final number, e.g.: `git diff-tree --shortstat HEAD~30 HEAD` produces `135 files changed, 774 insertions(+), 494 deletions(-)`

Comment: @torek - thanks for the technical details on how to solve the problem. I'll use that as a starting point if I decide to create the tooling. I was hoping that this type of tooling already existed based on the premise that this should improve productivity and quality by guiding developers towards smaller, higher frequency PRs.

Comment: It might, but I have not seen any. In all the places I've worked, we prefer human reviews. (We do use automated checking, but for the code itself rather than for the patches.)